# How Can I Publish a Google Sheets Template and Google Apps Script as a Project for Download?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, publish

I've created a Google Sheets template that I think could be useful for many people, and I'd like to share it with the community. The template includes Google Apps Script functions that are mapped to buttons within the spreadsheet.

I'd like to publish this template in a way that allows others to download a copy of the spreadsheet and its associated Apps Scripts to their own Google Accounts, where users can fill in and use the spreadsheet.

Any guidance, tips, or resources you can share would be greatly appreciated. I want to make sure this template is as accessible and user-friendly as possible for the community. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from your question. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a sharable link to your spreadsheet (with viewer, editor, or commentator privileges), change the /edit portion of the URL to /copy. This will give the recipient of this link the option to copy the spreadsheet and associated apps script to their own google drive. For example:

The link I got for one of my spreadsheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gjpp4alVVswP5DKU5WYHlwoM2YiCzuAdpGpSI4JNqvs/edit?usp=sharing

The link that will allow the recipient to copy my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gjpp4alVVswP5DKU5WYHlwoM2YiCzuAdpGpSI4JNqvs/copy

Answer (score -1):

1. Share the template's URL or a copy link.
   [Copy the sheet link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW5sB.png)
2. Share the Apps Script if not included in the template.
3. Provide clear documentation and support.
4. Share in relevant communities(Linkedin,Google developer community,Quora,etc).

Comment: Would sharing that URL/copy link give the user access to my local copy of the spreadsheet? Or would it create a copy of my spreadsheet in their google drive?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely. I already attached a screenshot for this information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).